# getResponse in c# not working. No response coming back

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I have this code in C#:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.Timeout = 30000; 
request.Method = "POST"; 
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
newStream.Write(bPostData, 0, bPostData.Length);

byte[] buf = new byte[1025]; int read = 0; string sResp = "";
HttpWebResponse wResp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream resp = wResp.GetResponseStream();
```

The line `HttpWebResponse wResp =...` just hangs (as in no response from the URL). I'm not sure where exactly its crashing (cause i dont even get an exception error). I tested the URL in IE and it works fine. I also checked the bPostData and that one has data in it.
Where is it going wrong?

Comment: http://test.abc.com/newtest .. Normal URL

Comment: @henk. yes i did wait 30+ seconds.

Comment: Try adding `http` to your url. It should throw `UriFormatException` if   anything so I'm not sure why it hangs on that line.

Comment: This could be a firewall issue. Your security may allow requests from browsers (IE/Firefox/Safari) post a request through port 80 but the HttpWebRequest from your app may not be allowed.

Answer (score 3):

Try closing the request stream in variable newStream. Maybe the API waits for it to be done.

Comment: You definitely should close the request stream. Otherwise there's no guarantee that all of the post data will be written. And if you don't close the stream, you can quickly run out of connections. See the remarks at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4cek6cc.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

You have to increase the limit:

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10; // Max number of requests
```

Answer (score 0):

Try simplifying your code and faking a user agent. Maybe the site is blocking/throttling scrapers/bots. Also ensure your `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` HTTP POST values are properly encoded. For this I would recommend you [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx):

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
    var values = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "param1", "value1" },
        { "param2", "value2" },
    };
    byte[] result = client.UploadValues(url, values);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I commented earlier, I had run your code at my office (heavily firewalled) I got the same result you did. Came home, tried again (less firewalled) it worked fine... I'm guessing you have a barrier there. I believe you are facing a firewall issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use a content-length=0

Example:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentLength = 0;
        var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        res.Close();
```